# Parse xml response text having cData in c#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I am getting response from web service in xml format and data are inside cData section in xml nodes. now when i am trying to extract node value then getting value with cdata text. how can i remove this and get text inside cdata. Please suggest me the best way of doing it. write now i am using regular expression to remove cdata from the result value. Thanks in advance.![!CDATA[Xyz]].

```
<ResumeParserData>
    <ResumeFileName><![CDATA[]]></ResumeFileName>
    <ParsingDate><![CDATA[3/29/2012 1:37:33 AM]]></ParsingDate>
    <TitleName><![CDATA[]]></TitleName>
    <FirstName><![CDATA[abc]]></FirstName>
    <Middlename><![CDATA[Kr]]></Middlename>
    <LastName><![CDATA[abc]]></LastName>
    <Email><![CDATA[xyz@gmail.com]]></Email>
    <Phone><![CDATA[+91 8527502445]]></Phone>
</ResumeParserData>
```

Comment: - <ResumeParserData>
  <ResumeFileName><![CDATA[]]></ResumeFileName> 
  <ParsingDate><![CDATA[3/29/2012 1:37:33 AM]]></ParsingDate> 
  <TitleName><![CDATA[]]></TitleName> 
  <FirstName><![CDATA[abc]]></FirstName> 
  <Middlename><![CDATA[Kr]]></Middlename> 
  <LastName><![CDATA[abc]]></LastName> 
  <Email><![CDATA[xyz@gmail.com]]></Email> 
  <Phone><![CDATA[+91 8527502445]]></Phone> 
- <ResumeParserData>

Comment: @Anu - can you show us the code you're using for attempting to parse it currently?  Showing the xml data is nice, but we can't help you debug the cdata issue if you don't show us what you're trying :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> right now i am using regular expression to remove cdata from the result value

Well I'd stop using regular expressions to parse XML to start with.

Use an XML API - LINQ to XML is lovely, for example. This should *transparently* let you get at the text, without you even having to know it was ever in a CDATA section unless you really want to. For example, with an XML file like this:

```
<parent>
  <child>
    <![CDATA[Foo]]>
  </child>
</parent>
```

We can get to the text like this:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        var child = doc.Root.Element("child");
        var text = child.Value;
        Console.WriteLine("Text: {0}", text);
    }
}
```

EDIT: With a slight change to the code above:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
        foreach (var child in doc.Root.Elements())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}",
                              child.Name, child.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

... when I run that on the XML in the question, I get:

```
ResumeFileName:
ParsingDate: 3/29/2012 1:37:33 AM
TitleName:
FirstName: abc
Middlename: Kr
LastName: abc
Email: xyz@gmail.com
Phone: +91 8527502445
```

Comment: but i still getting cdata in my text.

Comment: @Anu: It's hard to know what you're doing wrong as you haven't updated your question with what you're now trying.

Comment: @Anu - In case it helps, since you mentioned this is a web response, if you have the string already, you'll use XDocument.Parse instead (Load is for loading from a file, as Jon shows)

Comment: @JamesManning: Or a `Stream`, which would be more suitable for a web response: `XDocument.Load(webResponse.GetResponseStream())`

Comment: code abv working but when i tried this with actual then fails. when i saw my response as text i found &lt; before and after cdata is this happening due to this.  <ResumeParserData><ResumeFileName>&lt;![CDATA[]]&gt;</ResumeFileName>
  <ParsingDate>&lt;![CDATA[3/29/2012 3:33:07 AM]]&gt;</ParsingDate>
  <TitleName>&lt;![CDATA[]]&gt;</TitleName><ResumeParserData>
  <FirstName>&lt;![CDATA[xyz]]&gt;</FirstName>
  <Middlename>&lt;![CDATA[Kr]]&gt;</Middlename>
  <LastName>&lt;![CDATA[abc]]&gt;</LastName>
  <Email>&lt;![CDATA[xyz@gmail.com]]&gt;</Email>
  <Phone>&lt;![CDATA[+91 123456789]]&gt;</Phone>

Comment: @Anu: Right, those aren't CDATA sections. The angle brackets are escaped. As far as XML is concerned, that's just plain text. You should work out *why* you're getting XML like that. Looks like something's double-encoding...

Comment: i can't change response of service. any other way of doing this? or using regular expression is the right way of doing this.

Comment: @Anu: No, using a regular expression is *not* the right way of doing this. You could parse *the text itself* as "embedded XML" but that's pretty horrible. You should at least *talk* to whoever's giving you this data, and find out *why* it's like that... it's fundamentally a nasty bit of data...